# How to click on an element or the other using if-else logic using Selenium and Python for automated bot

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, selenium-webdriver, try-except

I'm automating a bot to book a certain time (preferred time and second preferred time).
I need help to use if else statement to allow the browser to search for the preferred time and if not present to search for the second preferred time.

Below is my code:

```
preferred_time=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="booking-start-time-label"][contains(., "12:33pm")]')
preferred_time.click()
second_preferd_time= driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="booking-start-time-label"][contains(., "1:33pm")]')
second_preferd_time.click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ideal approach will be to try to click on the initial desired element inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and incase it fails catch the *`TimeoutException`* and attempt to click on the second desired element as follows:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="booking-start-time-label"][contains(., "12:33pm")]'))).click()
except TimeoutException:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="booking-start-time-label"][contains(., "1:33pm")]'))).click()
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: issue is both could be clickable at the same time in certain situations and in this case we need a solution to make the browser choose the preferred time instead of the second preferred time

Comment: The answer code will always click on the first preferred time. Incase that fails then only fets the second. If the first is successful, the except part won't get executed ever.

Comment: i got an error that timeoutexception is not defined pylance(reportUndefinedVariable)

Comment: Why not try with both with an | between them as xpaths then you can handle the except.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan can you please clarify more how can i do that

Comment: @undetectedSelenium thank you that was helpful ,just a question what if i need to add two more preferable time. so now we have 4 preferable times instead of two

Comment: [Try, Except, else and Finally in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/try-except-else-and-finally-in-python/)

Comment: @undetectedSelenium could you clarify more how can i do that, pardon me i'm very new to that

Comment: Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium apologies i’ve just found that any code after this one is not working, i thought may it lacks a “then” do something or other ?